# Spring Boot data in the database is updated after running the data status checking process

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, maven, jpa

I am frustrated because of these blocks of Java code that I write. I write these blocks of code to check the seat availability status of data and then save the reservation data. After the comparison process, I noticed that the data in my master seat table have been updated and I am pretty sure that the code is not supposed to update the data in my master seat table. Here is the snippet of the code.

```
public List<CheckInSeatResponse> getGroupSeatData(Long serviceId, Date departDate, String departGroup, String destinationGroup, Long busId) {
    try {
        List<CheckInSeatResponse> manifestData = manifestPassengerRepository.getGroupSeatData( departDate, departGroup, destinationGroup, busId, serviceId);
        return manifestData;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

```
public List<Seat> getGroupSeatMap(Long serviceId, Date departDate, String departGroup, String destinationGroup, Long busId) {
    try {
        List<CheckInSeatResponse> manifestData = getGroupSeatData( serviceId, departDate, departGroup, destinationGroup, busId);
        List<Seat> seatData = seatBusRepository.findByBusIdOrderByIdAsc(busId);
        List<Seat> seatMap = new ArrayList<>();
        if (manifestData != null) {
            for (Seat seat : seatData) {
                Seat newSeat = seat;
                for (CheckInSeatResponse seatCheck : manifestData) {
                    if (seatCheck.getSeatNumber() != null && seatCheck.getSeatNumber().equals(seat.getSeatNumber())) {
                        newSeat.setSeatStatus("notAvailable");
                    }
                }
                seatMap.add(newSeat);
            }
            return seatMap;
        } else {
            return seatData;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

And here the check process code

```
List<Seat> seats = manifestService.getGroupSeatMap(
        reservation.getServiceBusId(),
        reservation.getDepartureDate(),
        depart.getGroupDestination(),
        destination.getGroupDestination(),
        request.getDepartBusId());
for (DetailCheckInResultResponse passenger : request.getPassenggerDepart()) {
    for (Seat seat : seats) {
        if (passenger.getSeat().equals(seat.getSeatNumber()) && "notAvailable".equals(seat.getSeatStatus())) {
            response.setStatus("failed");
            response.setMessage("Seat " + seat.getSeatNumber() + " not available");
            return response;
        }
    }
}
if (reservation.getReservationType()) {
    List<Seat> seatRets = manifestService.getGroupSeatMap(
            reservation.getServiceBusId(),
            reservation.getReturnDate(),
            destination.getGroupDestination(),
            depart.getGroupDestination(),
            request.getReturnBusId());
    for (DetailCheckInResultResponse passenger : request.getPassenggerReturn()) {
        for (Seat seat : seatRets) {
            if (passenger.getSeat().equals(seat.getSeatNumber()) && "notAvailable".equals(seat.getSeatStatus())) {
                response.setStatus("failed");
                response.setMessage("Seat " + seat.getSeatNumber() + " not available");
                return response;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong with this code block?

My env detail

- Spring Framework : 2.3.1
- Java : 1.8.0_211
- Maven plugin : 2.22.0
- DBMS : PostgreSQL 13.8

Please help. Thank you in advanced.

Regards,

David

I've tried to convert the data into list of string and parse it into JSON so the data won't be changed. It works but I am sure that requires much more resources so I'm expecting the seat status in the master seat table was not updated after saving reservation data with my current code.

Comment: Extremely out of date all the frameworks you are usign Spring Framework or spring Boot are ancient old... Which Maven plugin? (assumption surefire 2.22.0) also ancient old... JDK version 1.8 .. is not even on current state (1.8....382??) ... Also the code has some design flaws because eaiting up exceptions and returning  null is a really bad idea... there are optionals or just giving back an empty list for not finding something. The so called checked code? Is this a kind of unit test?

Answer (score 1):

It might be helpful if you provide a little more information on what the master seat table is represented as. Is your master seat table represented as a JPA Entity? Is that what Seat is?

In any case if you are setting some data on a Seat object it's quite possible that it's getting persisted after a flush. It can be flushed by some triggering event or if your code is wrapped in @Transactional.

You might also look for any CascadeType.PERSIST on any of your entities as this will also potentially add additional data to other entities that you may not be expecting.

One thing to try would be to turn on the debug log level with hibernate show queries set to true. This may help you track down where in your code the errant persistence is happening.